# Network is unreachable, destination host unreachable

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, gentoo, gateway

I give up at this point. I've been at this for hours. I've installed Gentoo onto VirtualBox and *somehow*, I don't know how, I broke my internet connection, and as it happens to be, I don't have dhcpcd or any other network utility installed (which I also don't know how happened). I've attempted to chroot via livecd but for some reason it can't find bash. Then I tried to manually configure it, to no avail. Keeps coming up with one of the two errors in title.

The only things I can ping are `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.1.1`.

As of present,

`route -n`:

[image]

`ifconfig`:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Please don't post images of text. Many people have a hard time reading them, or can't read them at all, and search engines can't analyze them. I realize that you don't have access to your VM via a copy/pasteable interface, but you could manually copy the essential elements of your routing table and IP configuration.

Comment: Your problem is that you configured 192.168.1.1 as gateway and also as the IP address of enp0s3. You have no route to anything but 192.168.1.1, which is your present system.

Comment: @berndbausch I tried changing the gateway to `192.168.1.2`, which I suspect is still wrong, as I'm still getting `Network is unreachable`. What should I be changing it to?

Comment: You should change the gateway address to your gateway's address (which I don't know, since I did not set up your network) and set the VM's IP address to something different. By the way, depending on the type of network attachment you configured for your VM, Virtualbox may have a DHCP server.

Comment: @berndbausch Okay, I'm using `bridged` mode which is supposed to make the VM use the same network adapter as the host, so I changed the ip address to `192.168.101`, and the gateway remained the same. I'm no longer getting `Network is unreachable`, but I still can't ping 8.8.8.8 and etc...

Comment: Give it the same gateway as the Virtualbox host, and ensure that there is a default route.

Comment: @berndbausch Well, I did give it the same gateway, what do you mean by default route?

Comment: You need to educate yourself on the fundamentals of computer networking. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route.

Comment: Ah, I think I've found the source of the problem... In an attempt to get Systemd working, I removed netifrc, but I don't know why dhcpcd was also removed... maybe I never had it in the first place? I thought I did. I still have some parts of the net-misc package, so I really don't know what happened

Comment: I feel a little stupid now... Instead of chrooting I just brought up `route -n` and `ifconfig` in the livecd, and copied the settings over into my install, and it worked. A couple particular things I noticed that were different was that the metric in the livecd was 202, whereas I never set the metric to 0 in my install. Also, the livecd used `192.168.1.203` rather than `192.168.1.1`.

Comment: The metric is not important in your case, as you probably only have one route per destination. I wonder, however, where the live CD's IP address came from. It's very likely that you do have a DHCP server in your network. How else does the live CD know your network address?

Comment: Because the livecd has dhcpcd, whereas the install does not. Also... I was trying to install networkmanager for redundancy, stupid me not knowing you can't have dhcpcd and networkmanager at the same time, and now dhcpcd comes up with `DNS configuration: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.` I added a `resolv.conf.tail` file and it worked again, only temporarily. I managed to re `emerge dhcpcd` but unfortunately that didn't seem to fix it

Comment: Alright I fixed it by using `systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service` from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1427311/activation-via-systemd-failed-for-unit-dbus-org-freedesktop-resolve1-service) and rebooting. Question can be closed now.